# In or-tools, VRPTW, how can I build a constraint that uses the fewest vehicles?

Tags: python, or-tools

python 3.6, or-tools 9.3.10497

Because my business scenario is more complicated, I will simplify it to describe.

There are two kinds of nodes, normal nodes and special nodes. If the vehicle only passes through special nodes or does not pass through any nodes, it is considered that the vehicle has not been used. My idea is that once a vehicle passes through a normal node, give that vehicle a count "1" and count it only once.

For example,

```
nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]
norm_nodes = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]
spec_nodes = [15,16,17]
depot_no = 18
vehicles = [0,1,2]
```

And node 15 only allows vehicle 0, node 16 only allows vehicle 1, node 17 only allows vehicle 2.

I try to build a constraint like this:

```
def vehicles_used_callback(from_index, to_index):
    from_no = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_no = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    if from_no in norm_nodes:
        vehicles_used_dimension.CumulVar(from_index).SetValue(0)
        return 1
    return 0

vehicles_used_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(vehicles_used_callback)
routing.AddDimension(vehicles_used_callback_index, 0, 999999999, True, "vehicles_used")
vehicles_used_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie("vehicles_used")

for vehicle_index, vehicle_no in enumerate(vehicles):
    index = routing.End(vehicle_index)
    vehicles_used_dimension.SetCumulVarSoftUpperBound(index, 0, 1)
```

But it doesn't work. The solution assigns only two nodes to each vehicle (one of which is a special node that only the vehicle is allowed to), and the remaining nodes are all dropped with a huge cost.

Like:

```
assigned_vehicles:
{
    0: [0,15],
    1: [1,16],
    2: [2,17]
}

dropped_nodes:
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

solution.ObjectiveValue()
1200000003
```

The result in actual business scenario is:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the constraint that you want to model ? :)

Comment: @watchdogs132 As the title says, I want to build a constraint that uses the least number of vehicles